# Function to Save/DumpSave without specifying full path

Tags: function-construction, save, dumpsave

I am trying to create a function that saves a set of symbols into "test.mx" and is easy to use.

```
list = {a,b,c}; f[x_] := x^2; z = 12.45;
save["test"][list,f,z]
```

In my attempt, something is saved, because the resulting file is not empty, but I cannot retrieve it. I suspect that the original symbols (list,f,z) are evaluated in the moment of passing the arguments to the function, and the symbols are lost.

Following other related posts, I tried a few things with `Hold`, `Evaluate`, `Unevaluated`, `ToString`, without success. Any comment would be much appreciated.

My attempt:

```
Clear[save]
save[where_][what__]:=Module[{directory,symbols},
directory=NotebookDirectory[]<>"/save/"<>where<>".mx";
If[! DirectoryQ[DirectoryName[directory]],
    CreateDirectory[DirectoryName[directory]]];
    symbols={what};
DumpSave[directory,symbols];]
```

Comment: I think it's a scoping issue, because this works outside of a `Module`: `directory = NotebookDirectory[] <> "/save/";
DumpSave[directory <> "test.mx", {z, f, list}]; SetDirectory[directory];
<< test.mx`

Comment: Yes it works outside Module. That's why I thought it was relevant enough to create the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The working function might look like the one below

```
Clear[save3]
save3[where_String][what__] := 
 Module[{directory}, 
  directory = 
   FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], "save"}];
  If[! DirectoryQ[DirectoryName[directory]], 
   CreateDirectory[DirectoryName[directory]]];
  Export[FileNameJoin[{directory, where <> ".mx"}], {what}, "MX"]
  ]

    list = {a, b, c}; f[x_] := x^2; z = 12.45;
    
    save3["test"][{list, f, z}]

(* "/home/acus/save/test.mx" *)
```

Then

```
    (data = Import["/home/acus/save/test.mx"]) // LeafCount
(* 8 *)

data
(* {{{a, b, c}, f, 12.45}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But neither list nor z are defined with this function. Also f[2] remains unevaluated

Comment: I use Export to save in Mma memory dump format "MX" only really huge pieces of data (many GB), which takes long time to compute. From my point of view to run definitions and to make assignments takes almost no time, so I never save them. Fresh session is always a best way to continue with necessary data loaded. By the way, the "MX" format is very Mma version and OS system dependent. Only use it for short time projects. The "WDX" format is much more universal, but also a lot slower. I can't help you with DumpSave.